# problem with error handling of c# application

Tags: c#, error-handling, mvp

i'm implementing bulltain board(or forums) for my website and i'm using MVP pattern in c# and asp.net along with a typed dataset to connect to the database. my problem is that i'm not sure where should i handle the possible errors and validate the incoming/outgoing data. i came up with two different solution:

**solution 1:**

`view:` do nothing just pass the data to presenter

`presenter:` validation and error handling related to model, database and the view

`model:` do nothing just return data or error from database

**solution 2:**

`view:` validation and error handling related to pages and user inputs

`presenter:` do nothing just be the mediator

`model:` validation and error handling related to database and model`

so which solution is a better approach??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I woulds personally stand for second solution for

> view: validation and error handling related to pages and user inputs

this. As it's important for simple (f.e typing errors) give the user immediate feedback, not making him wait for response from the model.

Answer (score 1):

I'd absolutely recommend solution 2.

Validate as much as possible in the view, so that most of the time the user can expect the interaction to succeed, once they send the data. Validate again in the application to filter out invalid and/or manipulated requests and apply domain specific rules.

Please remember that, since MVP is a UI pattern, the model is just data containers assembled by the presenter. Domain model, business logic, database access and therefore the ultimate validation should be located underneath the MVP-based UI layer in the application itself.

Comment: dennis thanks for your response but i don't understand what do you mean from "the ultimate validation should be located underneath the MVP-based UI layer in the application itself". do you mean i have to create some other application??

Comment: MVP is a pattern for the user interface layer. It has nothing to do with your application, domain or even data access layer. The Model in MVP ist just the Model for the specific View. Not the model of your domain.

Comment: well i'm not creating a layered application so the mvp is the application. but why mvp is a UI pattern?? what the UI has to do with the model that is connected to database?

Comment: The model that is connected to the database has nothing to do with what incidentially is also called "Model" in MVP. Please refer to Wikipedia as a starting point to learn what MVP is and what it isn't: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter

Comment: dennis can you help me implement the MVP in the correct way here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357779/i-have-a-problem-implementing-the-mvp-pattern-in-c-and-asp-net